# Whats wrong with my SPI code using uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, spi

I am stuck reading A1335 sensor through SPI. I have asked on the Aduino forum under the "Networking.." topic but no one is helping.
[Link to other forum post](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=671666.0)
I have changed the code so many times now that I am completely confused. Noob at understanding the data sheet, my problem mite have something to do with timing. Noob at SPI , I think my arduino-SPI code is where I went wrong.
Almost certain my wiring is good.
latest code:

```
/* ******************************************************************************
 *  SPI read 3x A1335 rotation sensor chips with UNO and display on serial monitor 
 *  Slave select pins 10 >ss1, 9 >ss2, 8 >ss3
 */
#include <SPI.h>

  // set slave pins and variables
  const int ss1 = 10;
  const int ss2 = 9;
  const int ss3 = 8;
  uint16_t Ang_ss1 = 0;
  uint16_t Ang_ss2 = 0;
  uint16_t Ang_ss3 = 0;

/*SPI settings here and not declared globaly for attaching different
  spi devices with difrent settings. Call transaction,begin with new
  settings*/

SPISettings settingsA(10000000,MSBFIRST,SPI_MODE3); //mode and 10mHz from manual, MSBfirst is a guess 


void setup() {
   //set slave pins High and as outputs

  pinMode (ss1,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite (ss1,HIGH);
  pinMode (ss2,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite (ss2,HIGH);
  pinMode (ss3,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite (ss3,HIGH);

  //set up register once and receive data in loop
  SPI.begin();           
  Serial.begin(9600); //in different post it's said Serial.begin must be before SPI.begi......true or false
  SPI.beginTransaction(settingsA);
  digitalWrite (ss1,LOW);
  SPI.transfer(0x20);
  SPI.transfer(0);
  digitalWrite(ss1,HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();

}

void loop() {


SPI.beginTransaction(settingsA);

//select sensor 1 to 3 and read registers 0x20 and 0x21 after I get First 1 working

digitalWrite (ss1,LOW);      // sensor one read and store two bite data in ANG_ss1
//Ang_ss1 = SPI.transfer(0x20); //0x20 and 0x21 angle register
Ang_ss1 = SPI.transfer(0); // receive data 0x20 high byte
Ang_ss1 = <<8;
Ang_ss1 |= SPI.transfer(0);//receive low byte
digitalWrite(ss1,HIGH);

SPI.endTransaction();

//De-bug code: display values from sensors
Serial.print(Ang_ss1,BIN);              //Serial.print Ang_ss1 in binary
Serial.println(" ss1     ");
Ang_ss1 = <<4;  //firs 4 bytes are not part of angle
Ang_ss1 = >>4;
Serial.print(Ang_ss1);Serial.println(" ss1 shifted");


Serial.print(Ang_ss1 * 360/4096 );  // formula from programming manual for sensor removed brackets from '(360/4096)'
Serial.println(" DEG   ");

delay (1000);                       // to read serial monitor for debugging
}
```

The relevant data sheet and programming manual is linked in **link** up top. There's only 3 relevant pages in programming manual, page 21-23.
Also a video of output to serial monitor and garble I got on my oscilloscope.
Will only be back home tomorrow to test latest code on oscilloscope.

new [Video](https://youtu.be/Pfc9XWMC2xc) of whats going on. New code uploaded but same problems. 
Reminder data sheet and such in link at start of post.

Progress: seems uno 5V out not enough for three sensors. I am getting better results with just one. here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cinWOV9JqD0) Still need help with code please

Confirmed can only run 1x SPI and when using I2C it becomes buggy with 2x sensors but one works a treat.
new [Video](https://studio.youtube.com/video/lwUd1JU6t8A/edit)
And code:

```
/* ******************************************************************************
 *  SPI read 3x A1335 rotation sensor chips with UNO and display on serial monitor 
 *  Slave select pins 10 >ss1, 9 >ss2, 8 >ss3, UNO: SCL 13, Miso 12, mosi 11.
 *                                                  pink     yelo       orange
 **********************************************************************************/
#include <SPI.h>

  const int ss1 = 10; const int ss2 = 9; const int ss3 = 8;          //slave select pins
  uint16_t Ang_ss1 = 0;  uint16_t Ang_ss2 = 0; uint16_t Ang_ss3 = 0; //store 16bit register
  float Chip1; float Chip2; float Chip3;                             //after math valaue with commas( deg out of 360)

  SPISettings settingsA(10000000,MSBFIRST,SPI_MODE3);               //Spi settings


void setup() {

  pinMode (ss1,OUTPUT);                       //set slave pins High and as outputs
  digitalWrite (ss1,HIGH);
  pinMode (ss2,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite (ss2,HIGH);
  pinMode (ss3,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite (ss3,HIGH);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  SPI.begin();           

}

void loop() {


SPI.beginTransaction(settingsA);

//select sensor 1 and read 0x20 and 0x21 registers

digitalWrite (ss1,LOW);                          // sensor one read and store two bite data in ANG_ss1
Ang_ss1 = SPI.transfer(0x20);                              //0x20 and 0x21 angle register
Ang_ss1 = Ang_ss1 <<8;
Ang_ss1 |= SPI.transfer(0);                               //receive low byte 0x21
digitalWrite(ss1,HIGH);

SPI.endTransaction();

Ang_ss1 = Ang_ss1 <<4;                                    //first 4 bytes are not part of angle
Ang_ss1 = Ang_ss1 >>4;
Chip1 = (float) Ang_ss1 / 16;                             // change binary to desimal
Chip1 = (float)Ang_ss1 /4096.0 * 360.0;                  //  formula in manual is n*(360/4096)

Serial.print(Chip1);               
Serial.println(" DEG   ");

//delay (2000);                       // to read serial monitor for debugging

}
```

Comment: Lines like this `Ang_ss1 <<8;` do nothing. I guess you want to write the result back into the `Ang_ss1` variable? Have you forgotten the equal sign?

Comment: Yes I forgot the equal sign. I will change that thank you, still not getting angle from sensor.

Comment: Please show the pure data, that you receive from the sensor (not some calculated value), so that we can see, if the SPI code itself works or not

Comment: chrisl, I am about to board a bus to airport. Hopefully I will have 'the latest code' tested and oscilloscope attached to see what code does by 13.00 today. Up to now just received one constant value through serial monitor

Comment: You may have to set the SPI pins to output yourself

Comment: Sim Son,  I have solved the problem. I had a power supply issue. The code now works but only for one sensor. I saw it was preferred to edit original Q? rather than comment down here. See last part of original post.  How do I mark this Q as solved or answered or what ever?